# perl, how to know if a command execution is asking password?

Tags: perl

I need to execute a command through perl script, if it asks for password to execute i need to ignore otherwise i can proceed further.

```
my $cmd = `ssh root\@192.168.1.1 '/bin/cat /root/a.txt'`;
```

Comment: Use ssh key authentication.

Comment: why not look at using something like Net::SSH::Perl? http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-1.37/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm  which you can tell to use key auth, and if it fails, move to the next one, as opposed to trying to capture exit codes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides using something like [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) like I suggested above.  You can enable batchmode

```
my $cmd = `ssh -oBatchMode=yes root\@192.168.1.1 '/bin/cat /root/a.txt'`;
```

if batchmode is set to yes, it will disable the querying of password/passphrase, which makes it pretty useful in scripts